# jQuery ContentFlow does not load all images

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have integrated a ContentFlow slideshow into my website.

- contentflow: http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/
- test site: http://www.bennoerni.ch/test.html

The problem is:
The slideshow does not load all images. (See test link above).

The problem has already been described here:

- http://www.jeremyckahn.com/blog/?p=61
- http://code.google.com/p/contentflow/issues/detail?id=3

The suggested solution "use v.1.0.0" does not work in my site. If I do so, the height of the contentflow div is not large enough - it hides half the slideshow. And I could not get it bigger via CSS.

I spent a fair amount of time searching for the bug.
I found the line that changes the behaviour between v.1.0.0 and v.1.0.2. (line 452 in v.1.0.2)

```
this.content.onload = window.setTimeout(foobar, 100);
```

v.1.0.0

```
this.content.onload = foobar;
```

I also tried all the code pieces in the google code link above. Could not get it working.

I would highly appreciate any help!

I think the easiest would be to use v.1.0.0 and try to fix the CSS. But I don't know how to do this because the CSS is set by ContentFlow.

Answer (score 0):

check comment 41 here: http://code.google.com/p/contentflow/issues/detail?id=3
Fixed it for me.